# What is the difference between intuition and conjecture in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, intuition, conjectures

I don't know any difference between intuition and conjecture.

In my opinion: A conjecture is a mathematical statement that has not yet been rigorously proved. Conjectures arise when one notices a pattern that holds true for many cases. Conjectures must be proved for the mathematical observation to be fully accepted. When a conjecture is rigorously proved, it becomes a theorem, and intuition is prediction of any thing and how it will be in the future.

> **Question:**
>   What is the difference between intuition and conjecture in mathematics ?

Comment: I agree with your opinion!

Comment: The question belongs to linguistics (of the English language), not to mathematics.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, if it is linguistics problem, why mathematicians used the term " conjecture" widely than  "intuition" term ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik they are in fact different things, I have explained the difference below...

Comment: I'm afraid you are asking at the wrong place. The difference between intuition and conjecture in mathematics is the same as the difference between intuition and conjecture in any other context in the English language.

Comment: My opinion is that your question was a good and interesting question, was put on hold but I like it (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Intuition is a quality someone has, a conjecture is a statement someone makes. Intuition leads to conjectures.

For example: Riemann's intuition led him to believe that all the zeros of the zeta function lie on the critical strip. This led him to make a conjecture that all the zeros of the zeta function lie on the critical strip.

Comment: I don't know why people here want to close this question however it's hard to get the difference at all

Comment: A conjecture is a statement someone makes, in fact I think it's best to think of conjectures as unproven statements. If a conjecture is proven it becomes a theorem. I can make a conjecture that something is true, for example I can conjecture that all odd numbers are prime. Intuition is not a statement. Someone with intuition can make a conjecture. Intuition is a quality, like being clever or being funny. People want the question to be closed because it's not mathematical, it is a question for linguistics. You are asking about the meaning of two words.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, when someone says something like

> intuitively, this is how it works ...

it's more a way of thinking about something. Usually not something rigorous.

A conjecture is something that is thought to be true (with good reason). Some conjectures can be numerically checked for many many cases and shown to be true but usually "impossible" to check for every possible case (for example if it's a statement about integers, there are infinitely many integers to be checked).